# One query to get records where cells are in different table

Tags: mysql, sql

Table users:

```
user_id     user_username   user_password
-----------------------------------------
1           tomasr          NULL
```

Table useritems:

```
f_user_id   f_moduleItem_id     userItem_value
--------------------------------------------------
1           1                   John
1           2                   Wayne
```

Table modules:

```
module_id   module_systemTitle  module_title
------------------------------------------------
1           users               Users
```

Table moduleitems:

```
moduleItem_id   f_module_id     moduleItem_title    moduleItem_order
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               1               Firstname           1
2               1               Lastname            2
```

Hello everybody,
how to get list of users with data from useritems table like one row with one user. That is mean number rows eqal number users.

Desire result is:

```
user_id user_username   firstname    lastname
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

1       tomasr          John         Wayne
```

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) to join two tables together. The link will explain it better but something like this:

```
SELECT u.user_username, i.userItem_value 
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN userItems i ON u.user_id=i.f_user_id;
```

What this will do is return all rows where a match is found but remember that if there is not a row in the userItems that matches the users table row then the users row will not be included in the results. For that you will want to look at LEFT JOINS and use IFNULL(something like that).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.user_ID,
        a.user_username,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c.moduleItem_title = 'Firstname' THEN b.userItem_value ELSE NULL END) `Firstname`,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c.moduleItem_title = 'Lastname' THEN b.userItem_value ELSE NULL END) `Lastname`
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN useritems b
            On a.user_ID = b.f_user_id
        INNER JOIN moduleitems c
            ON b.f_moduleItem_id = c.moduleItem_id
GROUP   BY a.user_ID, a.user_username
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/111be/1)

Comment: Good, but Firstname, Lastname are completely editable (can be there, needn't or can call differently). Simultaneously there can be other items (email, phone, etc.).

Comment: Is possible to make it general.

Comment: You know titles in table moduleitems can be editable ... for example instead Lastname can me just Name. That is reason why cannot be these keywords in query.

Comment: i think you want, dynamic query. so let me ask this, is the current query ok? but only you want to select specific titles? like displaying only firstname instead of firstname and lastname?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. Query is ok, but are there keywords like Firstname or Lastname. Which inputs admin chooses (table moduleitems) is up to him. If he decides to user form will contain 10 inputs I need get all users with these 10 inputs. So it's dynamic query, I'm sorry If I explained badly. Your solution is on good way, but it is possible to change it for my need?

Comment: Basicly items in moduleitems can call arbitrarily as admin wants and can be arbitrarily amount. Because of this query can't contain keywords from table moduleitems.